# how to get values of radio button

Tags: javascript

hi iam trying to get the values of the radio buttons from this page [text](https://go2.bucketforms.com/sf/4b2a4fae) and every time i get undefined or
`caught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'addEventListener')`

this is the code i did for now

```
btn=document.querySelector(".buttonNext");
btn.addEventListener("click", function radio() {
selected=document.querySelector(".css-1crzc9r:checked");
console.log("selected");
});
```

if it get past to the btn.addeventlisetner i still has the problem of Undefined am i doing something wrong maybe select wrong class or something but i already tried all the classes and they all give me undefined
i fixed it by adding

```
window.onload=function(){
  btn=document.querySelector(".buttonNext");
btn.addEventListener("click", function radio() {
console.log("error");
selected=document.querySelector(".css-1crzc9r:checked");
console.log("selected");
});
}
```

but now nothing happens i don't get anything

Comment: Please add a sample HTML to get a better answer here perhaps

Comment: `function radio() ` can just be `function()`

Comment: Please provide a [mre].

Comment: Define button properly with `var`, `let`, or `const`. ex. `const btn = document.querySelector(".buttonNext");`

Comment: `console.log("selected");` will just print "selector". `console.log(selector.value);` will print the value of the checked radio. Once again use `var`, `let`, or `const` when defining `selector`.

Answer (score 1):

There is couple of problems with your code:

1. Probably you are binding to html element when the DOM is not finish loading.
2. You were targeting html radio element using totally wrong selector. When im inspecting your code, none of your radio element have class `css-1crzc9r`

Try below code:

```
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(e) {
    const elem = document.querySelector(".buttonNext");
    
    elem.addEventListener("click", function() {
        let val = document.querySelector('input[name="options"]:checked').value;
        console.log(val)
    });
});
```